# How to Map to abstract conditionally

Tags: c#, inheritance, mapping, automapper

I'd like to map a common object to an instance of an abstraction (concrete instance of the abstraction) without saying which concrete instance I want. I want to choose the concrete instance based on a condition which will be set up in mapping configuration.

Like here:

```
ConstructUsing(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Label) ? (X)new XLabel() : new XValue())
```

and here:

```
m.Map<X>(i2); //where X is an abstraction
```

**Data**

```
// Source
public class Input
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

//Base target
public abstract class X
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }
}

//Concrete target 1
public class XLabel : X
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Concrete target 2
public class XValue : X
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**CONFIGURATION:**

```
//config
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Input, XLabel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Label));

    cfg.CreateMap<Input, XValue>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount));

    cfg.CreateMap<Input, X>()
    .Include<Input, XLabel>()
    .Include<Input, XValue>()
    .ConstructUsing(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Label) ? (X)new XLabel() : new XValue())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.P1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
});
```

**MAPPING:**

```
//Test
Input i1 = new Input { Id = 1, Amount = 2, };
Input i2 = new Input { Id = 1, Label = "my label" };
IMapper m = new Mapper(config);
var result1 = m.Map<X>(i1);
var result2 = m.Map<X>(i2);
```

Notice that I'm doing this:
`var result1 = m.Map<X>(i1);` not this `var result1 = m.Map<XValue>(i1);` *-And this is what I wanted to do -I wanted to Map to abstraction not to a concrete instance*

**TESTS:**

```
Assert.IsType<XValue>(result1); //PASSED
Assert.IsType<XLabel>(result2); //PASSED

Assert.Equal("my label", ((XLabel)result1).Name);// Message: Assert.Equal() FAILURE Expected: my label; Actual:   (null)
```

**Problem:**

Looks like this mapping does not work:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<Input, XLabel>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Label));

    cfg.CreateMap<Input, XValue>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Amount));
```

### Message: Assert.Equal() FAILURE Expected: my label; Actual: (null)

Comment: you can use an interface which implements `XLabel` and `XValue`, with an interface, you'll be able to do `var test = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Label) ? (IX) new XLabel() : new XValue()` , but from the your code above, it seems you need a Dictionary or a custom dictionary, which will be much easier to work with.

Comment: Since I'm using X which is an abstract class I don't need any extra Interface -right?  I know that I can manually do the condition and run the concrete mapping but is it stll AuoMapper? I wanted to use AutoMapper's methods/capatibilities. Thanks a lot for your advaice @iSR5